How to disallow camera sync from Mac to iPhone
After a recent iOS update, I got introduced to a new feature where my iPhone prompts me whether I want to connect and use the camera on the phone instead of the Mac when I enter a meeting and turn on my camera.
Is it possible to completely turn off this feature? I pretty much would never want to use my iPhone camera instead of the Mac's one when I'm using it.

That feature you are referring to is called Continuity Camera. You can easily disable it from your iPhone by:

Go to Settings
Scroll down and tap on General
Find and tap on AirPlay & Handoff
Find the option Continuity Camera and toggle it off.

This should disable it and you won't receive the prompts again.
